# Void pointer as struct array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, void

I was trying to use void pointer as `Struct` array to keep a few `struct` object together on disk.I want to write records to disk with using void pointer(think as a cluster consist of records).

```
void addRecordToDataPage(City record)
{
void* data = malloc(sizeof(City)*RECORD_COUNT);
FILE* fp;
fp=fopen("sampledata2.dat", "rb");
City pageofCity [RECORD_COUNT]; //City is my Struct.
if(!fp) //if it is first access, put the record to pageofCity[0]..
    {
    pageofCity[0]=record;
    data=pageofCity;
    writeDataPageToDisk(data); ..and call the write func.
    return;
    }

fread(&data, sizeof(City)*RECORD_COUNT, 1, fp);
int i=0;
while( (City *)data )
    {
    pageofCity[i] = ((City *)data)[i];
    i++;
    }
pageofCity[i]=record;


}
//and this is my writer function.
void writeDataPageToDisk(void* dataPage)
{
FILE* fp;
fp=fopen("sampledata2.dat", "a");
if(!fp)
    {
    fp=fopen("sampledata2.dat", "wb");
    writeDataPageToDisk(dataPage);
    }
fwrite(dataPage, sizeof(City)*RECORD_COUNT,1,fp);
fclose(fp);
}
```

in the line of `pageofCity[i] = ((City *)data)[i];` I got an memory error. 
This is my first question in this website, please forgive me about my errors :).

Comment: You should have read [ask] first. And provide a [mcve]. It is not really clear what you actually want. Pointers should not be stored in a file, as they are **very** likely not valid on the next run.

Comment: And format&indent this. It is unreadable.

Comment: There are stylistic and other issues with this code, but on quick glance your problem seems to be this line `while( (City *)data )`. `data` is never changed so this seems like an infinite loop.

Comment: Don't forget to close files that you open.

Comment: @MarcKhadpe: I agree that the loop you identify is problematic, and the loop won't terminate based on the condition.  However, `i` changes in the loop and is used to access a different `City` each time, so it will eventually crash with the subscript out of range.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, there are multiple problems with the code. Technically, accessing an out of bounds array element is undefined behavior, so a crash is not necessarily the result.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

The most likely cause for your error looks like:

```
while( (City *)data )
```

The value of `data` never changes and you are continuously reading a memory a byte ahead each time in the loop.

```
if (!fp)
{
    int recordsRead = fread(&data, sizeof(City), READ_COUNT, fp);
    int i=0;
    while( i < recordsRead)
    {
    }
}
pageOfCity[recordsRead] = record;
```

Also since you are appending one extra element to your array you will need to declare the extra space for that record.

```
City pageofCity [RECORD_COUNT + 1]; //City is my Struct.
```